# Populate UDP payload in socket programming with my own structure?

Tags: c, udp, raw-sockets

I want to send a variable of custom struct over udp sockets using sendto(). This struct contains UDP payload. When I googled a bit, I found that it is possible to create raw socket in c using the flag, SOCK_RAW, while creating the socket. But I think, then i will have to populate ip header as well as udp header too. I want to avoid that.

But when I tried sending the custom structure over socket as mentioned above, I receive different data ( not the structure contents) when sniffed with wireshark. Please help.

I tried changing the struct to normal uint32_t variable and used bit shifting operations to populate this variable. I confirmed that this variable has exactly the contents that I intended to add to it.

But again, I am not able to send this too over sockets. Wireshark displays different content. Is it because in sendto(), we provide the address of the buffer and not its value?

```
uint32_t disc_req[1];

//disc_req is populated with bit shift operations in the following function
create_discovery_req(disc_req);

//now disc_req has exactly the required binary format - I confirmed this  

// But the following sendto() sends different data. Confirmed over wireshark.  
sendto(sockfd, &disc_req, sizeof(disc_req), 
    MSG_CONFIRM, (const struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, 
        sizeof(servaddr));
```

Expeced output is value of disc_req sent over socket and the same captured on wireshark. But the actual value of disc_req is something different.

Comment: I was trying to fix it desperately.

Comment: @ikegami Edited. Please check now.

Comment: Sorry, tired. I think it's because you are weirdly using an array. I think `sendto(sockfd, disc_req, sizeof(disc_req), 
    MSG_CONFIRM, (const struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, 
        sizeof(servaddr));` will address the problem

Comment: I am using this array temporarily. It will be changed to something of size ~10. Finally, I need to send array contents completely over socket

Comment: What is the reason to use RAW sockets? How do you create your socket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different content you are observing may be due to the sender and receiver having different endianess (host vs network). If so you will want to use `hton...()` and `ntoh...()` when working with multi-byte values.

In general, when you send an array or struct over UDP, treat it like a byte array.

Create a UDP socket, not a RAW socket:

```
sockfd = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP );
```

Setup your destination address using the method you prefer (i.e. `gethostbyname()` )

Then send the payload:

```
sendto( sockfd, ( char* ) &disc_req[0], sizeof( disc_req ), MSG_CONFIRM, (const struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
```

To receive the payload:

```
recvfrom( sockfd, ( char* ) &disc_req[0], sizeof( disc_req ), 0, (const struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr) );
```

The following is a complete example sending an NTP packet using UDP:

https://lettier.github.io/posts/2016-04-26-lets-make-a-ntp-client-in-c.html

Comment: Thanks. How do I send the complete array over socket and not just disc_req[0]? I wanted to sniff it in wireshark in the exact same order.

Comment: Also, can you explain how I can get back the array from char * type in recvfrom()?

Comment: The & on disc_req[0] is the address of the first element, and sizeof (disc_req) is the entire length of the array.

Comment: I edited the answer to include how to receive the packet